# Invalid combination of type specifiers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, namespaces, compiler-errors, c++11

This works in xcode, but not visual studio.  The error is

error C2236: unexpected 'enum' 'abc::def::`anonymous-namespace'::'. Did you forget a ';'?

I can't figure out what is wrong.

```
namespace abc {
namespace def {

namespace {

long long enum {
  aaa = 1L,
  bbb = 2L,
};

}
}
}
```

Comment: Which language is this? This is definitely not legal C++98/03, and I'm not sure it's the correct syntax for C++11's typed enums. In any event, beware that MSVC2010 is a weird hybrid compiler whose language is a bit more than C++03, but not quite C++11, so you can't really expect anything.

Comment: Does msvc already support c++11 enums?

Comment: @PlasmaHH : Not full C++11 enum support, no, but it has allowed specifying the underlying type (using C++11 syntax) since VC++ 2005.

Comment: @ildjarn: Ah, ok, then my guess is that the OP somehow confuses C++11 and gcc extension syntax (since the syntax provided is a gcc extension)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That syntax is bizarre, I don't see how it would work anywhere (EDIT: apparently it's a GCC extension -- thanks @PlasmaHH). This is the portable C++11 syntax you want:

```
enum : long long {
    aaa = 1LL,
    bbb = 2LL
};
```